# Mshflexgrid not appearing in VBA "additional components"

Tags: vba, vb6, activex

I've registered Mshflexgrid and refer to it in VBA references, using Windows 64bits.
[image]

Unfortunately, I can't see it in the additional controls (no message). In other 64 bits desktops and in VB6 (in my computer), the component appears in additional controls.

[image]

Comment: That control is 32-bit only. That's why VB6 can list it; VB6 is 32-bit.

Comment: Wait, does VB6 show it or not?  The question states *In other 64 bits desktops **and in VB6** (in my computer), the component appears *

Comment: If the control on your computer is literally at "C:\windows\System32" as the first image says, then your computer is a 32-bit Windows.  32-bit controls on a 64-bit system are located in C:\windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: The issue was with Office64. I downgraded to Office32, and it works now. Nothing to do with the OS itself.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with Office64. I downgraded to Office32, and it works now. Nothing to do with the OS itself.